# Using SSIS to map hard coded values as part of a one-to-many table migration in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

Using SQL Server 2005 and Visual Studio 2005, I'm trying to create a SSIS package to merge data from 1 table to several other tables.

The source table does not have a several fields that the destination tables do. For example 'CreatedBy' and 'CreatedDate' fields. I would like these to be hard coded (in a sense) as part of the package import process.

The problem is not knowing what to use to facilitate this mapping. As a starting point it would be acceptable to have a hard coded '1' and GetDate() for createdBy and createdDate respectively.

The "Input and Output Properties" or "Column Mappings" tab on the "Advanced Editor for Destination" options dialog does not have any apparent support for mapping "default" values such as GetDate().

Any suggestions as how to achieve this?

Comment: I write SQL to get the data out of the source tables. In my source SQL, I specify all the missing columns so they match up. I can't say it's the most efficient way to accomplish the task, but it seems to work for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The SSIS way to create new columns (with static values or not) is to use the "Derived Column" transformation in your dataflow, in between the source and destination.

This enables you to specify additional columns and their values using an expression. For the current date/time, use `Getdate()` as the expression and set the datatype to "date (DT_DATE)". To hard code a value, double-quote it in the expression (e.g. "1") and specify the relevant data type.

Comment: Note: Non-derived columns will just pass straight through the "Derived Column" transformation block, i.e. from your source into your destination. (SSIS within SQL Server 2008).

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using a Table as a source, how about specifying the query specifically?  That way, you can statically define values as part of the source.

e.g.

```
SELECT id, fieldOne, fieldTwo, '1' AS createdBy, GetDate() AS createdDate
FROM SourceTable
```

I've done this exact thing recently.

One important thing to remember is that you need to make sure your datatypes match.  I had a few problems with string data types not matching up (UTF-8 and the like).

Comment: +1 for good suggestion, but this only works if you are defining a query as the source and the source is a 'SQL' source. You can't do this if you have defined 'Table or View' as the 'Data access mode' in an OLE DB Source for example, though of course you could use your technicque if the source is a View that you are able to modify.You can't do this for a file source such as FlatFile.